# spring cloud set logging.level does not work in application.yml(I have a logback-spring.xml, too)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-logback

these screenshot are my configurations about logback
logback-spring.xml

```
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

application.properties

```
logging.file.path=./logs
logging.level.cn.hsa=debug
logging.level.root=info
logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace
```

It’s not working when i change logging.level.root to debug or others in application.properties, it's always use this configure in logback-spring.xml

I read spring source code, logback-srping.xml loaded before application.properties
but i dont know why these configures were not override

Comment: You need to know that, logback-spring.xml always have the precedence on the loading because Spring Framework by-default uses logback framework for logging purpose. So, nothing is wrong here. It is doing what it is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can define something like this if you want to customize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="LOG_PATH" source="app.log.path"
        defaultValue="your_log_path" />

    <timestamp key="dateStamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <springProfile name="test,prod">
        <appender name="Access-FileAppender"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/logs/xyz.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
                </fileNamePattern>
                <!-- keep 90 days' worth of history -->
                <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <Pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>          
        </appender>
        <appender name="Async-Access-FileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
            <appender-ref ref="Access-FileAppender" />
        </appender>
    </springProfile>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>

    <springProfile name="local">
        <logger name="com.xxx.yyy" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="dev">
        <logger name="com.xxx.yyy" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="test,prod">
        <logger name="com.xxx.yyy" level="INFO" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        </logger>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, test/prod have the similar logging configuration. Similarly, you can configure for local and dev as well.
Hope this helps.